# Observer observable design pattern - Making a class with static members an Observer?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My class C1 has all static members (variables and methods). It also has an array A1 of Objects of type C2 which are observable. I want C1 to be an observer that notes changes in C2's and then applies those changes to the objects by using the references contained in A1. 
I am using an instance of C1 just so that it can be added as an observer of C2 objects.

Is the Observer-observable design pattern appropriate for this situation ? If yes, then am I applying it correctly ?

```
import java.util.*;

class FlightStatusChangeEvent{

int status;
Flight flight;

FlightStatusChangeEvent(int statusCode, Flight flight){

    this.status = statusCode;
    this.flight = flight;

}

public int getStatus(){return this.status;}

public Flight getFlight(){return this.flight;}


}

class Flight extends Observable{

int status;// 0 = on time, -1 = late, +1 = before scheduled time

public void updateStatus(int statusCode){


    this.status = statusCode;
    FlightStatusChangeEvent fsce = new FlightStatusChangeEvent(status, this);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(fsce);

}


}

class FlightStatusMonitor implements Observer{

public static ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

//keep calling this method every 10 sec to get latest flight status
public void displayStatusOfFlights(){

    //print all flight statuses in array list - flights
}

public void update(Observable flight, Object flightStatusEvent){

    FlightStatusChangeEvent fsce = (FlightStatusChangeEvent) flightStatusEvent;     
    Flight fl = fsce.getFlight();
    int status = fsce.getStatus();

    //find the flight in array flights and then update its status

}


}
```

Comment: Can you share some code? And that all static member class is a good anti-pattern. Can you change that?

Comment: Why FlightStatusMonitor.flights needs to be static? Without that you could do what you want.

Comment: @DiogoSantana - I am sorry, I am not able to understand the point you are making.

Comment: Answering your question: the observer desgin pattern is appropriate. You are on the right way of doing it. But take care with the static FlightStatusMonitor.flights member. If you have more then one instance of this class, you could have problems.

Comment: @DiogoSantana - Thanks. What are the problems that I could have ? Actually, i don't think that i will need more than one instance of FlightStatusMonitor. I know its a "static class", so there should have been no need to instantiate it. But, because its an observer I am forced to create an instance of it.

Comment: You could have problems related to multi threading. If this is a web app, you are using multi threads. Imagine two threads updating the list at the same time. You could have strange behaviors...

Comment: @DiogoSantana - can you give me an example of how the multi threading can make things wrong ?

Comment: There is a lot of possible problems, like this: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/what-is-race-condition-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Observer pattern can be implemented in your case:

```
class FlightStatusEvent {

    int status;
    Flight flight;

    FlightStatusEvent(int statusCode, Flight flight) {
        this.status = statusCode;
        this.flight = flight;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public Flight getFlight() {
        return this.flight;
    }

}

class Flight extends Observable {

    int status;// 0 = on time, -1 = late, +1 = before scheduled time

    public void updateStatus(int statusCode) {

        this.status = statusCode;
        FlightStatusEvent fsce = new FlightStatusEvent(status, this);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(fsce);

    }

}

class FlightStatusMonitor implements Observer {

    public ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

    public void displayStatusOfFlights() {
        for(Flight f : flights) {
            System.out.println("Flight " + f + ", status = " + f.status);
        }
    }

    public void update(Observable flight, Object flightStatusEvent) {
        displayStatusOfFlights();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlightStatusMonitor fsm = new FlightStatusMonitor();

        Flight f1 = new Flight();
        f1.addObserver(fsm);
        Flight f2 = new Flight();
        f2.addObserver(fsm);

        ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();
        flights.add(f1);
        flights.add(f2);

        fsm.flights = flights;
        fsm.displayStatusOfFlights();

        // this will trigger observer pattern event.
        f1.updateStatus(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Param why did you change the static members in my code to class members ? Does the O-O pattern fail for static classes ?

Comment: Theoretically, static fields/methods belong to the class (and not the objects). In your case, the flights object belongs to the FSM object, and not the class itself. O-O pattern can work with both static/non static methods/fields.