# Java - Combine Observer pattern with timer task?

Tags: java, design-patterns, timer, observer-pattern, timertask

In a previous post, I used the observer pattern. Description -

class Flight has a status (ie int) - before time, on time, late. This is my Observable
class FlightStatusMonitor has an ArrayList of Flights. This class is my observer. There is only one such observer. The update(Observable o, Object arg) method will update the status of the flight and also display the refreshed flight status of all flights that it observes.

I was thinking of using timer tasks to change the status of flights at chosen times and then see the updated status for all flights.

I want to be able to see the flight status displayed on the screen just after it is changed by a timer task.

But, I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Will concurrency will be a problem here ?

**UPDATE**
I have a set of flights whose status I will change in batches. Batch size can be 1 flight or more - 1 , 5 , 15 ,22 , 45 etc BUT NEVER all flights. I change the status for one batch, a couple of seconds later I change the status for another batch etc. Some flights remain unchanged.

[The related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594589/observer-observable-design-pattern-making-a-class-with-static-members-an-obser)

Comment: If you're gonna change the status of *all* flights at the same time, the observer pattern is useless. You might as well put a timer in your monitor and check all flights when it fires.

Comment: @Heuster - I have a set of flights whose status is changed in batches. Batch size can be 1 flight or more - 1 , 5 , 15 ,22 , 45 etc, BUT NEVER all flights. I change the status for one batch, a couple of seconds later I change the status for another batch etc. Some flights remain unchanged. Is the Observer pattern ok for this use-case ?

Comment: Yeah, then it would be great. If the number of changes is significantly smaller than the total number of flights, the Observer pattern would pay off. Moreover, you might want to cache the changes in a batch and update them all at a time (When a flight notifies a change, wait a while - a second, say - and add all  notifications that arrive within that interval in the same batch. Then, update the screen for the whole batch at once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `Observer` doesn't use any mutable state variable you won't have concurrency problems. Even that will be a problem only if you Schedule Task intersect. I mean start one Task before the previous finishes. If tasks are started sequentially it won't be a problem.

Comment: mutable state variable  - i don't understand. Please explain. Some tasks are started at the same time while some at another time.

Comment: I am accepting this answer for now. I hope you can respond to my comment

Comment: Mutable State variables means Instance or Static variables which can be modified. If all your variables are method scoped. Which means only exists within methods then you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: Notify Multiple observers on timer event.

Approach :

- Create Watchdog class which creates the timer and timer task.
- Observers register to Watchdog event.
- Watchdog class on timer event notifies the observers.

Sample Code below shows the scenario of combining timer tasks and observers:

// WatchDog.java

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

// Observer class

class Observer1 implements Observer{

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
System.out.println("Observer1 notified");
}
}

// Watchdog Component which creates the timer and notifies the timers.

public class WatchDog extends Observable {
    Timer timer;
    int seconds;

   // Notify task to notify observers

    class NotifyTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
        }
    }

    public WatchDog( ) {
        timer = new Timer(); 
    }

    public void schedule(long seconds){
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotifyTask(), 0, seconds*1000); //delay in milliseconds

    }

    public void stop(){
    timer.cancel();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Observer1 observer1 = new Observer1();

        WatchDog watchDog = new WatchDog();
        // register with observer
        watchDog.addObserver(observer1);

        System.out.println("WatchDog is scheduled.");
        watchDog.schedule(5);
        Thread.sleep(25000);

        watchDog.stop();
    }
}
```

For complete details refer to the article:  [Java timers and observer](http://assortedtechnotes.blogspot.in/2015/06/java-timers-and-observers.html)